# How can I enforce my threads to run in order?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to print the alphabet in order using threads. I got the letters printing but I'm having trouble getting them in the right order.

So I'm getting something like B,A,D,C

Is there a way to enforce the order of execution? I want thread 1 to go then wait, then thread 2, etc and then loop around again

Here is what I have:

```
public class Letters {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[] arr1 = new char[]{'A', 'E', 'I', 'M', 'Q', 'U', 'Y'};
        char[] arr2 = new char[]{'B', 'F', 'J', 'N', 'R', 'V', 'Z'};
        char[] arr3 = new char[]{'C', 'G', 'K', 'O', 'S', 'W'};
        char[] arr4 = new char[]{'D', 'H', 'L', 'P', 'T', 'X'};

        mythread c1 = new mythread(arr1);
        mythread c2 = new mythread(arr2);
        mythread c3 = new mythread(arr3);
        mythread c4 = new mythread(arr4);

        Thread t1 = new Thread (c1);
        Thread t2 = new Thread (c2);
        Thread t3 = new Thread (c3);
        Thread t4 = new Thread (c4);

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
        t4.start();
}

static class mythread extends Thread{
    char arr []; //= {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'};
    mythread () {};

    mythread (char [] x) {
        this.arr = x; // .arrcopy didn't work
    }

    public void run () {
        try {
            printletters(arr);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    synchronized void printletters(char [] arr) throws InterruptedException {
        int q = 0;

        for(int count = 0 ; count < arr.length; count++) {
            System.out.println(arr[count]);
            wait(10);
            q++;
            if(q >= 4) {
                notifyAll();
                q = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Put them into a single threaded `ExecutorService`

Comment: @MadProgrammer I've never used Executor service but I'm trying to do this using multiple threads. Is ExecutorService a single thread?

Comment: If you want them to run in order, why use threads at all?

Comment: ExecutorService is a very broad concept. It can create an executor that handles a single thread at a time or a bunch of threads (thread pool) at a time, and in many different ways. You'd best Google the term and read up on it.

Comment: @imalogginin Maybe start with [the Concurrency/Executors trail](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thanks I'll look into it

Comment: Take a look in `java.util.concurrent` at some of the tools for coordinating work between threads, like `Semaphore`, `CountDownLatch`, and `CyclicBarrier`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: Thread sequential order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12152493/java-thread-sequential-order)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To offer something other than what is already in the comments, here is a basic way to ensure that your threads run in order and will demonstrate one way to create custom synchronizers. A synchronizer is a means of controlling execution between threads.

There are many ways to solve this problem.  For simplicity, 4 synchronization objects will be used.  Each thread will 'block' on it's predecessor thread, print a letter, and when complete 'signal' its successor thread.  The blocking and signalling is achieved by the synchronizer.

Here is the Synchronizer:

```
public class TSync {

private final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
private final Condition previousThreadDone = lock.newCondition();
private boolean ready = false;  // Guarded by lock

public void waitForPreviousThread() throws InterruptedException {
    lock.lock();
    try {
        while (!ready)
            previousThreadDone.await();
        ready = false;
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}

public void signalNextThread() {
    lock.lock();
    try {
        ready = true;
        previousThreadDone.signal();
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}

}
```

And now your Letters class which now uses the TSync class to co-ordinate the execution flow:

```
public class Letters {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    char[] arr1 = new char[] { 'A', 'E', 'I', 'M', 'Q', 'U', 'Y' };
    char[] arr2 = new char[] { 'B', 'F', 'J', 'N', 'R', 'V', 'Z' };
    char[] arr3 = new char[] { 'C', 'G', 'K', 'O', 'S', 'W' };
    char[] arr4 = new char[] { 'D', 'H', 'L', 'P', 'T', 'X' };

    TSync sync1 = new TSync();
    TSync sync2 = new TSync();
    TSync sync3 = new TSync();
    TSync sync4 = new TSync();

    Mythread c1 = new Mythread(arr1, sync1, sync2);
    Mythread c2 = new Mythread(arr2, sync2, sync3);
    Mythread c3 = new Mythread(arr3, sync3, sync4);
    Mythread c4 = new Mythread(arr4, sync4, sync1);

    Thread t1 = new Thread(c1);
    Thread t2 = new Thread(c2);
    Thread t3 = new Thread(c3);
    Thread t4 = new Thread(c4);

    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t3.start();
    t4.start();

    System.out.println("Signalling Thread 1 is ready to work");
    sync1.signalNextThread();

}
}

class Mythread extends Thread {
private final char[] arr;
private final TSync waitOnSync;
private final TSync signalSync;

public Mythread(char[] arr, TSync waitOnSync, TSync signalSync) {
    super();
    this.arr = arr;
    this.waitOnSync = waitOnSync;
    this.signalSync = signalSync;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    boolean isInterrupted = false;
    for (int i=0; i<arr.length && !isInterrupted; i++) {
        try {
            waitOnSync.waitForPreviousThread();
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
            signalSync.signalNextThread();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            isInterrupted = true;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Now the alphabet will print in order (i.e. the synchronizers have ensured that each thread will run in the order you wish).