# Multiple threads running in the fixed order based on the compile order

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety

I am trying to figure out the multithreading order using the code below.
I use synchonized to block other threads while one is running in the synchronized part. I was expecting thread 1 should start and end first, then thread 2, finally 3. But the result showed always 1,3,2

So why this happen? Shouldn't be randomly executed like 1 2 3 or 1 3 2?

```java
public class hello {
    static class runnablethread extends Thread{
        private static int k = 5;
        public void run() {
            synchronized (runnablethread.class) {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " start:" + System.currentTimeMillis());
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000L);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " end:" + System.currentTimeMillis());
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        runnablethread r1 = new runnablethread();
        new Thread(r1,"Thread1").start();
        new Thread(r1,"Thread2").start();
        new Thread(r1,"Thread3").start();
    }
}
```

```sh
Thread1 start:1606114065880

Thread1 end:1606114066885

Thread3 start:1606114066885

Thread3 end:1606114067889

Thread2 start:1606114067889

Thread2 end:1606114068894
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java: Thread sequential order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12152493/java-thread-sequential-order)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Thread.start() method does not actually call your run method, it just indicates that your thread is ready to be scheduled for execution. The JVM then schedules the execution of the thread, but this scheduling does not guarantee that the order of the scheduling is the same as the order they were started.

In your specific case, the code sequence

```
new Thread(r1,"Thread1").start();
new Thread(r1,"Thread2").start();
new Thread(r1,"Thread3").start();
```

is executed quickly and the JVM ends up having 3 threads ready to be scheduled.

If you would want to wait for termination of certain thread, you can use join method.

It is also possible to alter the priority of the thread, using setPriority() method.

If the code is executed more than once, we can notice that the threads are started randomly

```
$ java hello
Thread1 start:1606124964911
Thread1 end:1606124965915
Thread3 start:1606124965915
Thread3 end:1606124966921
Thread2 start:1606124966921
Thread2 end:1606124967926

$ java hello
Thread1 start:1606124969152
Thread1 end:1606124970155
Thread3 start:1606124970155
Thread2 start:1606124971157
Thread3 end:1606124971157
Thread2 end:1606124972162

$ java hello
Thread1 start:1606124975920
Thread1 end:1606124976925
Thread3 start:1606124976925
Thread3 end:1606124977926
Thread2 start:1606124977926
Thread2 end:1606124978930

$ java hello
Thread2 start:1606124980589
Thread3 start:1606124981592
Thread2 end:1606124981592
Thread3 end:1606124982594
Thread1 start:1606124982594
Thread1 end:1606124983599
```

Comment: Actually I know the start() method is just for the schedule. But as you add thread 4 following thread 3, the execute order would be always 1,4,3,2, which means the order is reverse(start at the bottom sentence?) after thread1 has been executed?  Shouldn't be randomly executed like 1 4 2 3 or 1 2 4 3?

Comment: I have tried many times but always 1 4 3 2. I was surprised that your last result showed the thread 2 started first, which confirms the threads are started randomly. I am not sure why my result is always the same maybe it is because the software(not sure)? I use intelljj.

Comment: It might depend on operating system, current jvm version, number of processors and cores.